# How to prevent android app from crashing due to IOException in background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I wanted to know if there is a way in which the background thread that is trying to establish a connection on a passed uri string can be prevented from crashing the entire application due to `IOException` or `MalformedURLException`. 
While I catch all the exceptions thrown and print the messages out to logcat, I wouldn't want the app to crash all together with the msg: `Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped`. 
I would like the app to exit gracefully by posting a pertinent error message on the main/UI thread.

say for example:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    new Thread(new MyDownloaderClass(url_str)).start();
}

private class MyDownloaderClass implements Runnable{
    private String url_str;
    public MyDownloaderClass(String arg){url_str=arg;}
    public void run(){
        URL url=null;
    int respCode=0;
    try{
        url=new URL(str);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        connection.connect();
        respCode=connection.getResponseCode();

    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.getClass()+": "+e.getMessage());

    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.getClass()+": "+e.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

In this case my app just crashes if the entered string is not a  prasable url or a connection can't be made. But I want to be able post some useful message on UI thread and prevent the app from crashing.

thank you.

Comment: What is shown in the error trace in Logcat?

Comment: So if the user inputs some gibberish url and clicks the button, then I get 09-28 15:05:29.262: E/MyApp Activity(2940): class java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:  and then the app crashes. I want to handle this in a way that user is asked to check entered url by posting message on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Then put it in the catch part

```
catch (Exception e) {
     if(e.getMessage().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("write your exception from logcat"))
        {
         //show your error in a toast or a dialog
         Toast.makeText(this," your pertinent error message ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
```

Comment: hi manishika, I tired doing that. Since its a background thread I used the method runOnUiThread to create a toast on main thread to inform the user about bad input. But the app just crashes on catching the exception and does not create the toast on UI

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do all network operations in AsyncTask.

In doinBackground() of AsyncTask method, perform all network operations with try/catch. Handle the exception as below.

```
//Define "Exception error = null;" in your AsyncTask class.
catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.getClass()+": "+ex.getMessage());
    error = ex;
}
```

In onPostExecute() method check for

```
if (error ! = null) {
    //Toast msg . // You should not call a Toast msg in your doinBackground method.
}
```

Comment: hi pushkar,thanks for the reply. I wanted to know how it can be done without the use of async task.

Answer (score 1):

you're wrongly using Thread.start() instead of Thread.run():

```
          new Thread(new MyDownloaderClass(url_str)).start();
```

Your code still runs on the original thread, therefore on exception causing crash.